# Rename branch in firebase

Tags: jquery, firebase

I have a database structure

```
grabbit

     active

          category (ie womens bags, etc)

                 itemId

                       users who viwed this item (new branch)
```

A want to rename "active" to "inactive" when I want without having to move the data (especially the users who viewed this item part)

How can I change just the "active" name?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't rename nodes in Firebase without re-writing. To do a rename, you'll have to copy and delete the old branch. This snippet may be of use: https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6099042

Comment: will this also move/copy all the folders in the branch?

Comment: Yes, a copy will include all child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with Angularfire and the fallowing code updates only the parent node.

```js
$scope.addMeeting = function(){

        var key = $scope.editKey;   

        var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users/' + firebaseUser.uid + '/meetings/' + key);

        newPostKey.update({

            'name': $scope.meetingEditName,
            'date': Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        }); // Update Exicting Meeting
```

[image: firebase database]